# C# Watin element's click() function doesn't trigger ng-click

Tags: c#, angularjs, watin

I am gathering data from a webpage that uses angular.  I'm very familiar with the ins and outs of using Watin for data gathering.  This is the first time that I've hit a site using angular.

The element I'm having issues with is a list item.  Something like the following:

```
<li ng-class="eleID1" ng-click="detail.viewAllData(user.id)>
```

Normally, I'd use Watin and the Click function, for example:

```
List(Find.ByClass("std-list")).ListItems[0].Click();
```

I've even tried `FireEvent("onclick")` and other `FireEvents`, but nothing seems to trigger `ng-click`.  You can see on the webpage that the click is being fired, but it just doesn't perform the functionality that it's intended to.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say that you can "see on the webpage that the click is being fired". How are you doing that? One thing to keep in mind about AngularJS (and other SPA frameworks) is that they dynamically modify the HTML DOM after it is loaded. So if you were to get a reference to a page element, then perform some actions that cause the DOM to be modified, that reference may no longer be valid.

Comment: How about running detail.viewAllData(user.id) directly instead of trying to fire the click event? I know that this is not what you are requesting but I'm offering this as an alternative to you.

Comment: Jack, I can see that that standard click event is being fired because the line item has a brief highlight when this happens.  I'm clicking specific <li> items, which are presented in a row format.  The entire row highlights.  However, ng-click is not fired.  

To answer the second response, I've considered this, but how can I grab the Id, as it's being presented as merely user.id.   This is exactly what I'd like to do.

Comment: If you were able to get to that particular row to click on it you can also have the "user.id", it has to be somewhere in that row (hidden or not). Just replace it with the value and execute the action, that should do it.